# increase date column based on conditions

Tags: powerbi

I am having some issues with how to approach my query so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a date column that I need to increase based on two other columns values.

e.g. Date Reported column - 17/12/2018

If my Impact Column = "Urgent" and my Department = "Stores" I would need to increase my Date Reported Column to 18/12/2018

However if my Impact Column = "Standard" and my Department = "Floor" I would need to increase my Date Reported Column to 20/12/208

I would ideally like to not touch the original Date Reported Column but move this new value to another column.

So Far I have created a custom column and this is my code however it doesnt work.

`AmendedDateReported = if(And(SurveyCorrectiveAction[Impact] = "Urgent", SurveyCorrectiveAction[LookUp] = "Stores"), Date.AddDays([DateReported],1),Blank ())`

Thanks

Paula

Updated code, The formula seems to be pulling ok but the date part wont update:

```
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"DateReported", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows",{{"DateReported", type date}}),
#"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"DateReported", Order.Descending}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows1", "Date Repaired", each ""),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Date Repaired", type text}}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type1", "DateReported", "DateReported - Copy"),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{{"DateReported - Copy", "AmendedDateReported"}}),

#"Merged Amendments" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed Columns",{"Impact", "Department"},TLU_FaultTimeScales,{"Impact", "Department"},"TLU_FaultTimeScales",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
 #"Expanded Amendments" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Amendments", "TLU_FaultTimeScales", {"Amendment Day"}, {"Amendment Day"}),
  AmendedDateReported = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Amendments", "AmendedDateReported", each try Date.AddDays([DateReported],[Amendment Day]) otherwise [DateReported], type date)
 in 
 #"Renamed Columns"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
AmendedDateReported = 
    Table.AddColumn(
        #"Previous Step", 
        "Amended Date Reported", 
        each Date.AddDays(
            [Date Reported], 
            if [Impact] = "Urgent" and [Department] = "Stores" then 1 
            else if [Impact] = "Standard" and [Department] = "Floor" then 3 
            else 0 
        ), 
        type date
    )
```

If you have several combinations of Impact / Department which have variable effect on amending the date, it would make more sense to put those in a separate table:

```
+----------+------------+----------------+
|  Impact  | Department | Amendment Days |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| Urgent   | Stores     |              1 |
| Standard | Floor      |              3 |
+----------+------------+----------------+
```

You can then join this table to retrieve the amendment days:

```
    #"Merged Amendments" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Previous Step",{"Impact", "Department"},tblAmendments,{"Impact", "Department"},"tblAmendments",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Amendments" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Amendments", "tblAmendments", {"Amendment Days"}, {"Amendment Days"}),
    AmendedDateReported = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Amendments", "Amended Date Reported", each try Date.AddDays([Date Reported],[Amendment Days]) otherwise [Date Reported], type date)
in
    AmendedDateReported
```

Remember to update the final variable name after the `in` clause.

Comment: thank you, just one small question how would you recommend joining the tables, usually I would use a merge but this wont work as I have multiples with the same Impact - but I think you are correct I would be best joining these in a table format.

Comment: The merge in my answer joins the tables on both Impact and Department.

Comment: I have got the code to take without an error message flagging but when I select the apply the changes its erroring out with "The name 'Previous Step' wasn't recognized. Make sure its spelled correctly.

Comment: All seems to be running correctly now, but it doesn't seem to be picking up my days that need to be added on. Although I have matched up all the columns and amended as needed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question if necessary to clarify your problem - not the answer.

Comment: Apologies it wouldn't let me update the original in my other browser I have now swapped browser again and updated the original